# Concurrent file processing in data flow activity Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

When using control flow, it's possible to use a GetMetadata activity to retrieve a list of files in a blob storage account and then pass that list to a for each activity where the Sequential flag is false to process all files concurrently (in parallel) up to the max batch size according to the activities defined in the for each loop.

However, when reading about data flows in the following article from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern), they indicate the following:

> A mapping data flow will execute better
>   when the Source transformation iterates over multiple files instead of
>   looping via the For Each activity. We recommend using wildcards or
>   file lists in your source transformation. The Data Flow process will
>   execute faster by allowing the looping to occur inside the Spark
>   cluster. For more information, see Wildcarding in Source
>   Transformation.
>
> For example, if you have a list of data files from July 2019 that you
>   wish to process in a folder in Blob Storage, below is a wildcard you
>   can use in your Source transformation.
>
> DateFiles/*_201907*.txt
>
> By using wildcarding, your pipeline will only contain one Data Flow
>   activity. This will perform better than a Lookup against the Blob
>   Store that then iterates across all matched files using a ForEach with
>   an Execute Data Flow activity inside.

Based on this finding, I have configured a data flow task where the source is a blob directory of files and it processes all files in that directory with no control loops.  I do not, however, see any options to process files concurrently within the data flow.  I do, however, see an Optimize tab where you can set the partitioning option.

Is this option only for processing a single large file into multiple threads or does this control how many files it processes concurrently within the directory where the source is pointing?

Is the documentation assuming the for each control loop is set to "Sequential" (I can see why that would be true if it was, but having a hard time believing it if it's running one file at a time in the data flow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside data flow, each source transformation will read all of the files indicated in the folder or wildcard path and store those contents into data frames in memory for processing.

Setting the partitioning manually from the Optimize tab will instruct ADF the partitioning scheme you wish to use inside Spark.

To process each file individually 1x1, use the control flow capabilities in the pipeline.

Iterate over each file you wish to process and send the name of the file into the data flow via iterator parameter inside a For Each setting the execution to Sequential.

Comment: When you say "each source transformation will read all of the files indicated in the folder or wildcard path and store those contents into data frames" does it do that sequentially (one file at a time, process it, then load the next file...) or does it load multiple files up into data frames to transform them all concurrently?  I'm thinking it's doing it sequentially which is why one might do that in a non-sequential foreach control loop where a new data transform activity is started on each iteration.

Comment: Or is the article implying that it's better to just partition a single large file into multiple threads for importing (even if it does handle each file one at a time).

Comment: For parallel executions of multiple files, you should use the data flow Source wildcard/folder path. It's the same effect you'll get with ForEach with parallel executions.

The difference is that ForEach in will spin-up multiple job clusters with parallel and Azure will throttle you, so it performs poorly and drains resources.

Comment: Mark: Could you provide reference or information regarding how you know it's processing files in parallel? 
 When using the Copy activity (with control flow) where the source is a blob source connector, it specifically has options to specify the number of concurrent connections.  When using a for each control look, it specifically has a "Sequential" option along with an option for maximum concurrent iterations.  Yet, when using a source inside a data flow, I do not see any options that would control concurrency.  If the folder had 100,000 files, will it process 100,000 files at the same time?

Comment: From what I see on the documentation, the Wildcard paths option simply provides a way to override the folder path settings on the source (if needed).

Comment: "Wildcard path: Using a wildcard pattern will instruct ADF to loop through each matching folder and file in a single Source transformation. This is an effective way to process multiple files within a single flow. Add multiple wildcard matching patterns with the + sign that appears when hovering over your existing wildcard pattern."  Seems like it would do this one file at a time.

Comment: The data flow source reads from your path and hydrates data frames from those files. This gives you better performance because the data can be processed across all of those files against your Databricks cluster without needing to spin-up separate job clusters, which is would happens with ForEach in parallel.

You can see this in action in data preview. Set the "Column to store file name" in your Source options and view the file name associated with each row. Data flow will disperse your processing across the entire compute cluster.

Comment: BTW, I really appreciate your comments here. It seems I can make the documents a bit clearer. Can you let me know if these explanations make sense? I'd like to refresh the online docs to reflect a better understanding of this process. TY!

Comment: That clarifies it very well.  I'll perform the data preview and validate that all files are processed concurrently across the frames (thank you very much).  Now would the partitioning option just break a large file down even further by breaking a single file down into multiple frames (1 frame per partition)?

Comment: BTW - You are really providing the answer I need so just place it in an answer section and I'll accept ; )

Comment: I do find it interesting that there is no control for an upper bound on how many files it processes concurrently.  Even though all files are loaded up into frames, is it just taking turns getting row 1 from file1/frame1, row 2 from file2/frame2, etc?  That would explain why it doesn't care about how many at a time since its really doing one row of output at a time (across multiple frames).  Wouldn't true parallel processing be reading multiple file streams into the data flow where each one is concurrently writing that data to a sink?

Comment: All good points. I'm thinking that we'll need to add an enhancement request to allow you to provide concurrency control and options for processing order. You have some control over it today from the sink. You'll see a "Sink Ordering" option for your data flow. If you were to carve-up the files from your folder into different sinks (i.e. "*.csv" for 1 source->sink, "May*.txt" for another source) then you can set the processing ordering.

Comment: Understood.  I apologize, but I'm still not clear about whether or not it's just taking turns getting a row from each frame or whether it's gathering more than one row from multiple frames at the same time.  Sorry.

Comment: You can see it when you set the column file name property in the source options. From your data preview window, you'll see all of the rows from each file are read into dfs.

Now, hit refresh on your preview pane, and you'll likely see the order of the files being loaded change.

The ordering is non-deterministic, but each file is loaded individually.

Now, once you partition that data across nodes, the processing of those rows will get distributed and processed in parallel based on the nature of distributed processing.